# Plotting mean ROC curve from multiple ROC curves in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, scikit-learn, roc

I am trying to plot the mean ROC curve of a support vector machine (SVM) model with a linear kernel over 10 runs. The code fits the SVM model to the training data, and generates the ROC curve and its corresponding area under the curve (AUC) for each run. The mean ROC curve is then computed using the mean false positive rate (mean_fpr) and mean true positive rate (mean_tpr) obtained from all 10 runs. However, the resulting plot does not start at the origin (0, 0), indicating that there is an issue with the computation of mean_fpr and mean_tpr.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read the csv file
df = load_breast_cancer(as_frame=True)

# Split the data into features (X) and target (y)
X = df['data']
y = df['target']

from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc

# Number of runs
#random.seed(321)
n_runs = 10

# Lists to store the results
aucs = []
tprs = []
fprs = []

for i in range(n_runs):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=None)
    svclassifier = SVC(kernel='linear', random_state=i)
    svclassifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = svclassifier.predict(X_test)
    y_score = svclassifier.decision_function(X_test)
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, y_score)
    fprs.append(fpr)
    tprs.append(tpr)
    roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
    aucs.append(roc_auc)


# Mean ROC curve
mean_fpr = np.unique(np.concatenate(fprs))
mean_tpr = np.unique(np.concatenate(tprs))
mean_tpr = np.zeros_like(mean_fpr)
for i in range(n_runs):
    mean_tpr += np.interp(mean_fpr, fprs[i], tprs[i])
mean_tpr /= n_runs
mean_auc = auc(mean_fpr, mean_tpr)


# Plot the mean ROC curve
sns.lineplot(x=mean_fpr, y=mean_tpr, ci=None, label='Mean ROC (AUC = %0.2f)' % mean_auc)
plt.xlim([-0.1, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('ROC Curve')
plt.show()
```

The problematic line of code is as follows:

```
for i in range(n_runs):
    mean_tpr += np.interp(mean_fpr, fprs[i], tprs[i])
```

Can anyone help me identify and fix the issue with the mean_fpr and mean_tpr values so that the resulting plot starts at (0, 0)?

Comment: You lose all the estimated tpr values with this line: "mean_tpr = np.unique(np.concatenate(tprs))
mean_tpr = np.zeros_like(mean_fpr)", i.e. you overwrite them with zero.

Comment: The thing is that with the lines `mean_fpr = np.unique(np.concatenate(fprs))` and `mean_tpr = np.unique(np.concatenate(tprs))` I am not getting anymore the same dimensionality of the two arrays `np.concatenate(fprs)` and `np.concatenate(tprs)`.


The line `mean_tpr = np.zeros_like(mean_fpr)` was the only way I found to return `mean_tpr` to the same dimension of `mean_fpr`.

However is the function `np.interp(mean_fpr, fprs[i], tprs[i])` inside the for loop that  is causing the mean_tpr to "lose" the zero value (because the list tprs has less zeros than fprs).